# Implementing Android LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> is Throwing a Syntax Error

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

I'm doing the Loader Tutorial in the Android API Guides and I've copied it pretty much word for word.  I have API 16 installed, so I know I don't need to import the support library.

The only errors that I'm getting are for my class declaration:

```
public class GroupsFragment extends ListFragment implements OnQueryTextListener,  
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{

  .....
```

Errors I am getting are:

> ```
> Breakpoint:GroupsFragment
> Syntax error on token ".", delete this token
> Syntax error on token "LoaderManager", delete 
> this token
> ```

I am very new to development so I cannot figure this one out.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, but figured it out. Probably too late for a response, but if you import android.app.LoaderManager you should be fine. Note: if you're using Eclipse, it won't import automatically (even with content assist).

Comment: while working for api prior to v11 and using support library, import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;